# Controlar errores entre líneas del subnivel de una transacción

Tags: genexus

Tengo una transacción, pongamos por ejemplo:

```
EmpleadoId  *
EmpleadoNombre
....
....
    ( HorarioId *
      DiaSemana 
      HorarioDesde
      HorarioHasta )
```

Necesito que al hacer click en CONFIRMAR, de alguna forma se controle que  DiaSemana-HorarioDesde-HorarioHasta no esté ya comprendido en otra linea del mismo grid.

No se me ocurre que regla, o como controlar eso beforevalidate.
Alguna ayuda?

(Gx17 + Java)

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una regla *error* que se dispare *beforecomplete* llamando a un procedimiento que realice el chequeo que requieras:

En las reglas de la transacción pondrías:

```
error("Los horarios se solapan") if not ChequeaRango(EmpleadoId) on beforecomplete;
```

Luego creas un procedimiento `ChequeaRango` con las siguientes partes:

**Reglas:**

```
parm(EmpleadoId, out: &ok);
```

**Variables:**

```
DiaSemanaCol      collection de dominio Attribute:DiaSemana
HorarioDesdeCol   collection de dominio Attribute:HorarioDesde
HorarioHastaCol   collection de dominio Attribute:HorarioHasta
idx               Numeric(4)
ok                Boolean
```

**Source:**

```
&ok = true
for each Empleado.Horario
    for &idx = 1 to &DiaSemanaCol.Count
        if &DiaSemanaCol.Item(&idx) = DiaSemana and 
            (
                (&HorarioDesdeCol.Item(&idx) >= HorarioDesde and &HorarioDesdeCol.Item(&idx) <= HorarioHasta) or
                (&HorarioHastaCol.Item(&idx) >= HorarioDesde and &HorarioHastaCol.Item(&idx) <= HorarioHasta) 
            )
            &ok = false
            return
        endif
    endfor
    &DiaSemanaCol.Add(DiaSemana)
    &HorarioDesdeCol.Add(HorarioDesde)
    &HorarioHastaCol.Add(HorarioHasta)
endfor
```

Comment: Gracias por tanto detalle. No lo resolví exactamente como lo planteas pero me diste la idea de por donde ir. Gracias totales!

Answer (score 0):

Dejo aquí como solucioné:

En la trn empleados las siguientes reglas

```
ctrlErroresTrnEmpleados(EmpleadoId,&Mensaje,&HayError) on beforecomplete;
Error(&Mensaje) if &HayError on beforecomplete;
```

Luego un procedimiento ctrlErroresTrnEmpleados:
Rules:

```
Parm(EmpleadoId, out:&Mensaje, out:&HayError);

&Mensaje: Varchar(100)
&HayError: boolean
```

Source:

```
For each Empleado.Horarios order EmpleadoId,HorDia
    &HorarioId = HorarioId 
    &DiaSemana = DiaSemana 
    &HorDesde = HorDesde
    &HorHasta = HorHasta
    Do 'Chequear'
EndFor

Sub 'Chequear'
    For each Empleado.Horarios order EmpleadoId,HorDia
    Where DiaSemana = &DiaSemana 
    Where HorarioId <> &HorarioId 
    
        If &HorHasta > HorDesde and &HorDesde < HorHasta
            &Mensaje = 'Existen horarios superpuestos. Revise'
            &HayError = true
            return
        endif
    EndFor
endsub

&HorarioId numerico(2)
&DiaSemana = numerico(1) 
&HorDesde = datetime - sin fecha
&HorHasta = datetime - sin fecha
```

Saludos.